# Groovy closures - not understandable call order

Tags: groovy, closures

I try to build a small DSL, but I don't understand the following order of execution.

The DSL has a statement as `summarize tests of 'me'`

my Groovy script for interpretation is:

```
def tests = {
    [of: { who ->
            println "IN CLOSURE"
            "HALLO" // dummy value for testing
        }]
}

def summarize(Closure c) {
    println "SUMMARIZE - CALL CLOSURE"
    def f = c()
    println "SUMMARIZE - CALL CLOSURE"
    println "RESULT $f"
    f
}
```

and my caller script has

```
def g = summarize tests of 'me'
println g
```

The output is

```
SUMMARIZE - CALL CLOSURE
SUMMARIZE - CALL CLOSURE
RESULT [of:com.github.groovyclient.TestRailClient$_closure1$_closure13@470f1802]
IN CLOSURE
HALLO
```

I actually want to have the result of the `tests` closure already in the `summarize` method, but it seems that there the inner closure has not been called yet - what magic is happening after that so that the script does have the correct result ?

Can someone explain me, why the order of execution ? And how can I retrieve `HALLO` already in the `summarize` method ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `test` is a closure which returns a map.
If you call `test()` you'll get `[of: {...}]`

It's what you see in your console, when you print `f`.
For groovy

```
summarize tests of 'me'
```

is equivalent to

```
summarize(tests).of('me')
```

yours `summarize(tests)` execute `tests()`, which returns the map `[of:{..}]`. After that, you're executing `map.of` which return the close, and then you are calling this closure with the parameters `me`.

There are differents options to obtain what you want, but it depends on the full "dsl" you want to implement, not just this special usecase. The easiest way I think with only this sentence, is returning an intermediate object, which is triggered when you call `of':

```
def summarize(t) {
  return [
    of: { who ->
      def f = t().of(who)
      println f
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification - is there then any way to structure this, to have the result of the closure already available in `summarize `?

Comment: I have added an example of what can be done, but to be honest, it's ugly. You should define more precisely what do you want in your DSL ;-)

Comment: thanks again - the idea is to filter/map results. `tests of 'me'` is a closure that returns a set of results (full object information). `Summarize` would then e.g. only return the title of the results.

Comment: write it `summarize test.of('me')` then, if you want to call `test.of` and pass the result to `summarize`